# SimpleMembership - object 'Users' already exists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing SPA with Asp.net MVC. Project works on localhost fine, but i've a problem on hosting.

There is controller to work with `MembershipProvider` containg few methods.

```
[InitializeSimpleMembership]
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    public object Get()
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

The key moment - is the attribute `InitializeSimpleMembership`. It's declaration:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private static SimpleMembershipInitializer _initializer;
    private static object _initializerLock = new object();
    private static bool _isInitialized;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        // Ensure ASP.NET Simple Membership is initialized only once per app start
        LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
    }

    private class SimpleMembershipInitializer
    {
        public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new ITAInitializer());

            using (var context = new ITAContext())
            {
                if (!context.Database.Exists())
                {
                    ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
                }
            }

            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("ITAContext", "Users", "ID", "Login", autoCreateTables: true);

            if (!Roles.RoleExists(UserRights.Admin.ToString()))
                Roles.CreateRole(UserRights.Admin.ToString());

            if (!Roles.RoleExists(UserRights.Moderator.ToString()))
                Roles.CreateRole(UserRights.Moderator.ToString());

            if (!Roles.RoleExists(UserRights.User.ToString()))
                Roles.CreateRole(UserRights.User.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

When i'm calling any method in controller i'm getting an error:

> There is already an object named 'Users' in the database.

If i'm deleting table `Users` then first request running fine and creating the table. In the next call i'm getting an error again. Why it's trying to create table and not using existing?

Comment: Anything going on in `ITAInitializer` that might cause this?

Comment: @MikeGuthrie Nothing works with Users in ITAInitializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in rights of db user. After adding `VIEW DEFINITION` and `ALTER` my code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove this attribute from controller
2. Add method `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection` in some class:

   ```
   public static class AuthConfig
   {
       public static void RegisterAuth()
       {
           WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("ITAContext", "Users", "ID", "Login", autoCreateTables: true);

           if (!Roles.RoleExists(UserRights.Admin.ToString()))
               Roles.CreateRole(UserRights.Admin.ToString());

           if (!Roles.RoleExists(UserRights.Moderator.ToString()))
               Roles.CreateRole(UserRights.Moderator.ToString());

           if (!Roles.RoleExists(UserRights.User.ToString()))
               Roles.CreateRole(UserRights.User.ToString());
       }
   }
   ```
3. Call this method:

   ```
   public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
   {
       protected void Application_Start()
       {
           AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
       }
   }
   ```